# Water Image : Chemical Analysis

Tags: android, matlab, image-processing

I am sorry to post this question but I need some guidance for a project in MATLAB.

Is there any way via an Android App to take a image that can characterize the chemical components of water computationally?

I have to find the presence of Arsenic in water remotely. The lab attended would just take an image of the water - all he can do is send it remotely to me.

How using Image processing or rather what technology I can make use that I can detect chemical composition of the water as in the image?

Comment: Is there any chemical you can add to water to change the color if Arsenic is present? If so, you could have the user add that chemical and then the picture could help verify any slightest color change.

Comment: Thanks . Though not sure of that .... anyone from chemistry department can provide this help .. the solution should be cheap and readily available at remoter places

Comment: This is another research question that requires some literature review and a series of experiments. In order to know chemical properties of a matter, you have to have information related to wavelengths that you may not obtain with Android camera. I used the word "may" because at the end of the research, you may be able to use RGB camera but without the research, you may not know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you have to remember that StackOverflow is all about software issues (not about any particular application).

Regarding **your question**: I am afraid you cannot do it straighforward. First, given a RGB image like this one:

[image].

Could you tell me if the water contains arsenic or if the color is due to the mud? You cannot say that the water contains arsenic, so you cannot develop an application to perform this task.

You have two posibilities:

1. Use an spectrometer. But it is complicated to use it remotely.
2. Use some chemical tint to change the color of the image if it contains arsenic.

Now, the **software aspect**:

In the question title you talked about Matlab, but then you ask about Android... I am confused. Could you clarify that particular point?

Comment: Thanks I understand your point. Actually first the data needs to be captured at Android app as an Image and then will be processed via MATLAB for its chemical composition. So as stated by you we should use the other possibilities using some test data remotely and then do the analysis

Comment: +1 for a pictorial description of this unconstrained problem.